# How do I downgrade my php version from 7.3.4 to 7.0.0 in larvel 5.4.36?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to downgrade the version of php from 7.3.4 to 7.0.0 in my laravel project. Please suggest how to do it?

I am using artisan serve.

I am using laravel version 5.4.36

Comment: Are you using valet? Or homestead? or artisan serve?

Comment: I am using artisan serve

Comment: This is purely apache/nginx thing, as long as you will maintain the minimum required PHP version, you can downgrade and upgrade as you want.

Comment: You do know that certain versions of laravel require you to have versions of PHP installed higher than 7.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer might be a solution for you to downgrade your php version.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46786305/6654987

Answer (score 0):

these are the commands for downgrading from php 7.4 to 7.3 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php  
sudo apt-get update  
     
sudo apt-get install php7.3    
     
sudo a2dismod php7.4  
sudo a2enmod php7.3  
sudo service apache2 restart  
     
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3  
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.3  
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.3  
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.3  
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.3
```

Answer (score -1):

Try lower the Laravel version. Change the value inside the composer.json to Laravel 5.x, delete the vendor folder and run `composer install`.